# Drush Launcher does not work

Tags: drush, composer, 10

Drush Launcher gives an error in an environment updated to Drupal 10.2.
The environment is Drupal 10.2, PHP 8.2, Drush 12.4, Drush Launcher 0.10.2.
Specifically, I get the following error

```
[user@host drupal]$ drush status
The Drush launcher could not find a local Drush in your Drupal site.
Please add Drush with Composer to your project.
Run 'cd "/var/www/drupal" && composer require drush/drush'
```

However, Drush is installed by composer and is also listed in composer.json.
I have updated from Drupal 9, but I can no longer run the Drush command with only "drush".
I would like to be able to run it with "drush" instead of "vendor/bin/drush".
./bashrc or any other method other than passing it through $PATH, please.
The following from Drupal 9 is ideal.

```
[user@host drupal]$ drush status
...
Drush script     : /usr/local/bin/drush
...
```

Please help.

Comment: `This repository has been archived by the owner on Aug 19, 2023. It is now read-only.` https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher

Comment: Check some alternatives here: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher/issues/105.

Comment: I changed my mind about closing this question. It has a factual answer.

Comment: So Drush Launcher is not compatible with Drupal 10 and Drush 12, so there is no other way but to use it through $PATH?

Comment: Incorrect. Read the defunct project’s page for alternatives, as I wrote in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drush-launcher does not work because it is unmaintained. See [its archived project page](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher) for alternatives.